# Tslint to Eslint migration - Error after convert-tslint-to-eslint command

Tags: angular, typescript-eslint

I am migrating my project to ESLint from Tslint , i am following this [guide](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/03/31/migrating-from-tslint-to-eslint/) to convert and i´m stuck on this error after do the command:

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint  {{PROJECT_NAME}} --force
```

[image]

The error says:

> Cannot find angular.json

How can i solve this?
Should i wait to upgrade to angular 13 first? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the "." in front of the name file and the command recognized the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its better to run this command under angular project. Systems finds the folder as angular project when it gets the `angular.json` file and the project name can be usually under project section of `angular.json` file. If you are running this command in angular project where `angular.json` file is available, you do not require any dot or other relative path, just provide the project name.

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint  {{PROJECT_NAME}}
```